# Specify Platform Name on a POM XML surefire plugin

Tags: java, android, maven, appium

I am trying to setup [this project](https://github.com/saikrishna321/PageObjectPatternAppium) for Parallel Mobile automation using Intellij IDEA on a Windows 10 environment. When I run the project with the specified command "mvn clean -Dtest=Runner test -DPlatform=android" from the IDE terminal I have this output:

> [INFO] Running com.appium.tests.Runner [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures:
>   1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.247 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   com.appium.tests.Runner [ERROR] testApp(com.appium.tests.Runner)  Time
>   elapsed: 0.01 s  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Please execute with Platform environment:: Platform=android/ios/both
>   mvn clean -Dtest=Runner test
>           at com.appium.tests.Runner.testApp(Runner.java:14)

On my POM.XML under surefire plugin I put as a property variable ${Platform} which is not recognized by the IDEA with an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Platform' "

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <Platform>${Platform}</Platform>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try `systemPropertyVariables`

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
            <Platform>${Platform}</Platform>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```